# How to position a modeless dialog with respect to a document window in GMS3?

Tags: dm-script

Modeless dialogs appear to have changed significantly in GMS3, especially the methods for positioning such dialog windows.  Use of a dialog position specification (generated with the functions DLGBuildPosition and DLGPosition) to specify the initial dialog position no longer seems to work.  Directly positioning the dialog via methods on its associated DocumentWindow object (e.g. WindowSetPosition or WindowSetFrameBounds) seems to work, but the coordinate system seems inconsistently defined and not connected to the workspace coordinate system, the one used by document windows.

The sample scripts below illustrate the contrasts between the coordinate systems between these two types of windows.  Given this disconnect, is there any way to position a modeless dialog window with respect to a document window in a given workspace?

Here is some sample code the illustrates the fairly normal and expected coordinates returned for document window content areas and frames:

```
// $BACKGROUND$

// In GMS3, the DM app bounds give the size of the workspace area,
// i.e. the area in which document windows are positioned and presented.
// The bounds are in local DM workspace coordinates and do not yield the
// position in either DM app window or screen/display coordinates.
Number appT, appL, appB, appR;
ApplicationGetBounds(appT, appL, appB, appR);
String infoText = "Workspace frame: [";
infoText += appT + ", ";
infoText += appL + ", ";
infoText += appB + ", ";
infoText += appR + "]";
OKDialog(infoText);

Number windowCount = CountDocumentWindows();
Result("\nWindow count: " + windowCount + "\n");
for (Number iWin = 0; iWin < windowCount; iWin++)
{
    DocumentWindow window = GetDocumentWindow(iWin);

    Result ("\n\nTitle: " + window.WindowGetTitle());

    // In GMS3, document window bounds are specified and returned in
    // local DM workspace coordinates and do not yield the position
    // in either DM app window or screen/display coordinates.
    Number winT, winL, winB, winR, winW, winH;

    window.WindowGetContentPosition(winL, winT);
    Result("\nContent position: " + winL + ", " + winT);
    window.WindowGetContentSize(winW, winH);
    Result("\nContent size: " + winW + ", " + winH);
    window.WindowGetContentBounds(winT, winL, winB, winR);
    Result("\nContent bounds: " + winT + ", " + winL + ", " + winB + ", " + winR);

    window.WindowGetFramePosition(winL, winT);
    Result("\nFrame position: " + winL + ", " + winT);
    window.WindowGetFrameSize(winW, winH);
    Result("\nFrame size: " + winW + ", " + winH);
    window.WindowGetFrameBounds(winT, winL, winB, winR);
    Result("\nFrame bounds: " + winT + ", " + winL + ", " + winB + ", " + winR);

    window.WindowSetFramePosition(winL + 50, winT + 50);
    Sleep(3);
    window.WindowSetFrameBounds(winT, winL, winB, winR);
    Sleep(3);
}
```

For comparison, the following script shows the analogous values returned for modeless dialog windows:

```
// $BACKGROUND$
TagGroup uiItemsSpec;
TagGroup dialogSpec = DLGCreateDialog("Dialog title", uiItemsSpec);

// In GMS3, the DM app bounds give the size of the workspace area,
// i.e. the area in which document windows are positioned and presented.
// The bounds are in local DM workspace coordinates and do not yield the
// position in either DM app window or screen/display coordinates.
Number appT, appL, appB, appR;
ApplicationGetBounds(appT, appL, appB, appR);
String infoText = "Workspace frame: [";
infoText += appT + ", ";
infoText += appL + ", ";
infoText += appB + ", ";
infoText += appR + "]";
OKDialog(infoText);

// In GMS3, specification of an initial modeless dialog frame with a TagGroup
// returned by DLGBuildPosition and passsed to DLGPosition, no longer works.
// Instead, the window frame must be set directly via WindowSetFrameBounds.
Number winT = 100;
Number winL = 50;
Number winB = 300;
Number winR = 700;
// TagGroup positionSpec = DLGBuildPosition(winT, winL, winB, winR);
// positionSpec.TagGroupSetTagAsTagGroup("X", DLGBuildRelativePosition("Inside", 1));
// positionSpec.TagGroupSetTagAsTagGroup("Y", DLGBuildRelativePosition("Inside", 1));
// positionSpec.TagGroupSetTagAsTagGroup("Height", DLGBuildMatchSize());
// positionSpec.TagGroupSetTagAsTagGroup("Width", DLGBuildMatchSize());
// dialogSpec.DLGPosition(positionSpec);

// Create and add an info text field
TagGroup infoLabelSpec = DLGCreateLabel("Initial modeless dialog position", 48);
infoLabelSpec.DLGSide("Left");
infoLabelSpec.DLGExternalPadding(0, 0);
uiItemsSpec.DLGAddElement(infoLabelSpec);

Object dialog = Alloc(UIFrame).Init(dialogSpec);
dialog.Display("Positioned modeless dialog");
Sleep(3);

DocumentWindow window = dialog.GetFrameWindow();
infoText = "Frame bounds set to [";
infoText += winT + ", " + winL + ", ";
infoText += winB + ", " + winR + "]";
infoLabelSpec.DLGTitle(infoText);
window.WindowSetFrameBounds(winT, winL, winB, winR);
Sleep(3)

// In GMS3, modeless dialog title text is not stored as the window title,
// WindowGetTitle always returns an empty string.
Result ("\nTitle: " + window.WindowGetTitle());

// In GMS3, the coordinate system for modeless dialog window
// positioning appears to be unclear and inconsistent.
Number winW, winH;

// For the window content area, only the content bounds are easily understood.
// They specify the content rectangle in content area coordinates.
window.WindowGetContentPosition(winL, winT);
Result("\nContent position: " + winL + ", " + winT);
window.WindowGetContentSize(winW, winH);
Result("\nContent size: " + winW + ", " + winH);
window.WindowGetContentBounds(winT, winL, winB, winR);
Result("\nContent bounds: " + winT + ", " + winL + ", " + winB + ", " + winR);

// For the window frame, the frame bounds and size appear to be in screen coordinates.
// The frame position is in DM app window  content area coordinates.
window.WindowGetFramePosition(winL, winT);
Result("\nFrame position: " + winL + ", " + winT);
window.WindowGetFrameSize(winW, winH);
Result("\nFrame size: " + winW + ", " + winH);
window.WindowGetFrameBounds(winT, winL, winB, winR);
Result("\nFrame bounds: " + winT + ", " + winL + ", " + winB + ", " + winR + "\n");

infoLabelSpec.DLGTitle("Frame position set to (0, 0)");
window.WindowSetFramePosition(0, 0);
Sleep(3);

infoText = "Frame bounds set to [";
infoText += winT + ", " + winL + ", ";
infoText += winB + ", " + winR + "]";
infoLabelSpec.DLGTitle(infoText);
window.WindowSetFrameBounds(winT, winL, winB, winR);
```

Comment: Thanks for checking this in such detail. To my knowledge, this is a bug in porting the scripting language to GMS 3 which has so far not been noticed. In simplified terms, it seesm that scipt "documentwindows" do not work for dialogframes as expected. Despite being the "same" in script, they are no longer in the underlying implementation. (ImageDocuments were adjusted for the workspace concept and docking panes, all others were not.) Unfortunately I have not yet found a workaround (expect hardcoding the XY offset between the two for a given situation)

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I was hoping there would be some way to get at the layout of the DM app window, in particular how wide the left docking pane is and whether it is open.  That seems to be the main thing needed in order to establish the offset between the modeless dialog position origin and the workspace origin.

Comment: Yes. I'm afraid, there is none. (And the values are not 100% constant as they will depend on the OS's chosen system font size as well as "docked" vs. "free" vs. "collapsed" panes. A feature request/bug report has been filed.